# jQuery fisheye effect + mouse movement panning

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to combine a mouse panning effect with the fisheye plugin at http://interface.eyecon.ro/docs/fisheye.

These work fine separately, but together they go completely spastic

Is there anything that can be changed or added to the code below to smooth everything out?

Mouse panning:

> ```
> $("body").mousemove(function(e) {
>     var distance = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
>     var percentage = distance / $(this).width();
>     var targetX = -Math.round(($(".dock-container").width() - $(this).width()) * percentage);
>     $('.dock-container').animate({left: [targetX+"px", "easeOutSine"]}, { queue:false, duration:2500 });
> });
> ```

Fisheye:

> ```
> $('#dock').Fisheye({
>     maxWidth: 42,
>     items: 'a',
>     itemsText: '',
>     container: '.dock-container',
>     itemWidth: 40,
>     proximity: 90,
>     halign : 'center'
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at how the fisheye plugin works, you'll see it animates the `left` property of the `.dock-container`. Your mousemove code also animates the left property of `.dock-container`, so ultimately, your code is fighting fisheye. You should look into moving your code to animate a parent (say `dock`, or wrap `dock` in another div and animate that) so that the `left` animations don't fight each other. If you set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), we might be able to have a play around to try and fix it. Otherwise it's pretty hard to say whether my solution will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mousemove event should be placed on a wrapping div - also have a look at the [hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.